# How to save github secrets content in a file in github action

Tags: github, github-actions

I was trying to do the following :

`echo ${{secrets.key}} > myfile`

But unfortunately, this doesn't work since myfile would be empty after this when i checked.
How do i save the content of github secret into a file ?

Answer (score 10):

You can first pass the secret to an env var, then echo it to the file, remember to quote the env var to prevent line feed from breaking the command.

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: print secrets
      env:
        MY_SECRET: ${{secrets.KEY}}
      shell: bash
      run: |
          echo "$MY_SECRET" >> config.ini
          cat config.ini
```

Comment: you may need to add that now github actions require to setup a given environment name at job level : https://docs.github.com/fr/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenvironment

Comment: @boly38 my actions config still works without that. Is it mandatory? Did see the reference in the docs.

Comment: I suspect an old project is backwards compatible and this is useful for new projects only (without checking)

Answer (score 0):

Check that the `secrets.key` actually exists before doing the above.